# Crystal Reports - for do loop that cycles through an array of db fields

Tags: crystal-reports

Trying to make a formula calculate a string in a subreport, the code looks as follows

```
shared StringVar array aflProc := [{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_1},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_2},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_3},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_4},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_5},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_6},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_7},
{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_8},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_9},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_10},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_11},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_12},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_13},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_14},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_15},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_16},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_17},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_18},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_19},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_20},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_21},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_22},{V_APS_ATTRIB.TITLE_23}];
shared StringVar aflProc2;
local numberVar i;


    For i := 1 to 23 do (
        if aflProc[i] <> "" Then
        aflProc2 := aflProc2 & chr(10) & aflProc[i]
        else aflProc2
    );

aflProc2;
```

tried a few different methods of this, any advice on how to get my formula to output the string from a table of db fields would be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

remove the `else aflProc2`

and remove `aflProc2;` at the end, and then remove line breaks from your array at the top and this works